# Merge method in apex

Tags: apex, merge

In apex, there is merge method to merge accounts but I am confused about this method. Does this method merge all related object even if there is custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it merges all the related records irrespective of whether it is a standard object or custom object. This is as per the salesforce documentation

> The merge operation merges up to three records into one of the
>   records, deletes the others, and reparents **any** related records

Points you should keep in mind while using merge feature

- Only leads, contacts, and accounts can be merged
- You can pass a master record and up to two additional sObject records to a single merge method i.e. You can merge up to three records of the same sObject type
- Using the Apex merge operation, field values on the master record always supersede the corresponding field values on the records to be merged. To preserve a merged record field value, simply set this field value on the master sObject before performing the merge
- External ID fields can’t be used with merge

You can get more information on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) link.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: okey done. I didnt know that thank you again

Comment: Now Cases can also be merged via apex

Answer (score 2):

[According to this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm)

It merges duplicates. So if there are multiple it merges into single record and **REPARENT** children to one record.